# Kubernetes rejecting pod logs from local kubectl client

Tags: logging, kubernetes, rancher, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster, started using rancher on a host. I am trying to start seldom [http://docs.seldon.io/install.html] in it. I was able to start the pods, but not able to get the pod logs from `kubectl logs` command.

I get the error "Error from server (BadRequest): the server rejected our request for an unknown reason (get pods xxx)"

`kubectl version` shows the following :

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2",    GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

`Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5+", GitVersion:"v1.5.0-115+611cbb22703182", GitCommit:"611cbb22703182611863beda17bf9f3e90afa148", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-13T18:03:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with older version of Kubernetes and should be fixed in the latest, see this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38774) where this is discussed in detail.

I tried with the latest version and it works just fine:

```
$ kubectl log kubernetes-dashboard-1cvm4 --namespace kube-system
W0412 10:47:32.040258   13000 cmd.go:361] log is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use logs instead.
Using HTTP port: 9090
Creating API server client for https://10.0.0.1:443
Successful initial request to the apiserver, version: v1.6.0
Creating in-cluster Heapster client
Using service account token for csrf signing
```

Kubernetes Version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:36:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2017-04-07T20:43:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```